# Outlook Using Different Recipients in Envelope and Message

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have a user outside the company with the desktop version of Outlook for Office 365, and they are using an email service provided by their ISP (let's call them `peter.pan@neverland.com`). When they try to email someone inside my company (let's call them `wendy@darling.com`), the email arrives with the SMTP Envelope header [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) being addressed to the correct recipient (`RCPT  TO: wendy@darling.com`), but the mail header [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) is different and incorrect (`To: "'Wendy Darling'"@mx.mail.neverland.com`), and Wendy does not have an email address with the Neverland ISP.

This is problematic when there are CC addresses in our company and Wendy tries to reply-all. In other words, Peter Pan sends an email CC `wendy@darling.com`, `john@darling.com`, and `mike@darling.com`, and all three emails arrive because the SMTP envelope header is correct but the Mail message header has `Cc:"Wendy Darling"@mx.mail.neverland.com, "John Darling"@mx.mail.neverland.com, "Mike Darling"@mx.mail.neverland.com`. Now when Wendy (who is also using Outlook 365 on Windows desktop) tries to reply-all, the reply goes to `"John Darling"@mx.mail.neverland.com`, etc, which of course fails and bounces back saying there is no such address. The Peter Pan user has sent me the headers of one of his emails from the "sent" box, and the addresses will be formatted like `Cc: <Wendy Darling>, "'Tinkerbell'" <tink@neverland.com>, <John Darling>`. Based on this, it appears Outlook on Peter's computer is sending to an invalid address for Wendy and John, but a valid address for Tinkerbell.

This doesn't seem to happen all the time, we have had stretches of several weeks without issue. Over time all the users involved will end up with address book entries in Outlook something like `Wendy Darling <"Wendy Darling"@mx.mail.neverland.com>`. I have instructed all parties to purge such address book entries from "All Contact Items" (leaving correct address book entries), but after a while they come back (possibly due to Outlook auto-adding an invalid address from a received email, but I have no timeline proof of which is the cause and which is the effect).

I have contacted the Neverland ISP about the issue, and of course they say there is nothing wrong with their system. Having different addresses in envelope vs. message is a valid part of the RFCs, but we don't want it in this situation and based on the headers in Peter's "sent" email it does seem to be an issue generated by Outlook.

The Peter Pan user does not have issues with other recipient companies, and our company (Darling in my example) does not have issues with other senders. It only appears to be the combination of Neverland and Darling. Peter Pan isn't the only user with this problem either; `tinkerbell@neverland.com` has the exact same problem as Peter.

In a Stack Overflow [question about SMTP envelopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750194/why-does-email-need-an-envelope-and-what-does-the-envelope-mean), the accepted answer has a section:

> Most mail clients set the same addresses in SMTP RCPT TO: and MAIL FROM: commands that they insert in To:, Cc:, and From: headers, so the "envelope" addresses will be the same as the addresses in the headers.
>
> Envelope and header addresses will usually agree for most legitimate mail. Notable exceptions are Bcc: addresses and mailing lists.

but in Peter Pan's case neither BCC nor mailing lists are involved.

What could be causing Outlook to use different addresses in the mail header vs SMTP envelope? On the occasion I remotely accessed Peter's computer, I was unable to find an address book entry without a domain name. How would I find such a thing if that is the problem? For what other reason might Outlook be setting the different addresses, and how do I get it to stop?

Comment: How did the sender type the recipients' addresses(via auto-complete list or others)? Could the issue be reproduced if he type the address manually?
The easiest way to confirm if the issue is related to outlook desktop client is test on your web mail to check if the issue still exists there.

Comment: User finally responded to me, and I remotely logged in to their computer. I was unable to replicate the issue on either webmail or Outlook. Webmail will autocomplete the correct address (and goes through correctly). Outlook also will autocomplete correct address and goes through correctly. Manually typing the email "wendy@darling.com" or even "Wendy<space>Darling", Outlook will autocorrect to the correct address and go through correctly. The user's Outlook had address book entries with @mx.mail.neverland.com addresses that I have deleted, and hope will not return.

Comment: Sounds like there may be some wrong items in their autocomplete lists，anyway glad to see it could work normally now.By the way, it's recommended to switch your comment to answer and mark it.